# How to determine the position of an "icon" on the desktop (windows xp)?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, desktop

is it possible to read the position of a given "icon" on the desktop?
Or better, store them all and be able to restore them later (for instance after a change of resolution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some freeware utilities which you could use, for example

[**DesktopOK**](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Software/DesktopOK&language=english)

> Save and restore the positions of
>   icons. DesktopOK is a small but
>   effective solution for user that have
>   to change the screen resolution often.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the questions in your question detail text, rather than your question title, [yes, it's clearly possible :)](http://www.iconsaver.com/index.html)